# Quais arquivos devem ser inseridos no .gitignore em um projeto Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

Estou iniciando no Git e também no Ruby on Rails. Criei um novo projeto usando `rails new myapp -d mysql` e adicionei ao meu repositório do GitHub. Ao criar o projeto o rails gera vários arquivos.

Até ai tudo bem, mas acontece que alguns arquivos, que contém senha do banco de dados - `config/database.yml` (por exemplo) subiram para o repositório.

Gostaria de saber quais arquivos são recomendados que eu coloque no .gitignore, para que eu não exponha minhas informações de segurança, ou arquivos desnecessários que normalmente, não são adicionados ao repositório.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independente da linguagem para meus projetos eu sempre começo com o template do GitHub. E edito baseado nas minhas preferencias.

Você pode achar o de Ruby aqui: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Ruby.gitignore

Abaixo o conteúdo do arquivo em caso de *dead link*.

```
*.gem
*.rbc
/.config
/coverage/
/InstalledFiles
/pkg/
/spec/reports/
/test/tmp/
/test/version_tmp/
/tmp/

## Specific to RubyMotion:
.dat*
.repl_history
build/

## Documentation cache and generated files:
/.yardoc/
/_yardoc/
/doc/
/rdoc/

## Environment normalisation:
/.bundle/
/vendor/bundle
/lib/bundler/man/

# for a library or gem, you might want to ignore these files since the code is
# intended to run in multiple environments; otherwise, check them in:
# Gemfile.lock
# .ruby-version
# .ruby-gemset

# unless supporting rvm < 1.11.0 or doing something fancy, ignore this:
.rvmrc
```

E aqui para Rails:
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Rails.gitignore

Você pode adicionar o `config/database.yml` no .gitignore para que este seja ignorado, se for um repositório público e/ou você não queira expor sua senha do banco de dados.

```
*.rbc
capybara-*.html
.rspec
/log
/tmp
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal
/public/system
/coverage/
/spec/tmp
**.orig
rerun.txt
pickle-email-*.html

# TODO Comment out these rules if you are OK with secrets being uploaded to the repo
config/initializers/secret_token.rb
config/secrets.yml

## Environment normalisation:
/.bundle
/vendor/bundle

# these should all be checked in to normalise the environment:
# Gemfile.lock, .ruby-version, .ruby-gemset

# unless supporting rvm < 1.11.0 or doing something fancy, ignore this:
.rvmrc

# if using bower-rails ignore default bower_components path bower.json files
/vendor/assets/bower_components
*.bowerrc
bower.json

# Ignore pow environment settings
.powenv
```

Comment: Podes usar o https://www.gitignore.io/ para escolher as varias linguagens/frameworks/IDEs e obter um unico .gitignore concatenado.